# How to remove newline characters inside paragraphs with sed or awk

Tags: text-processing, command-line, newlines

I was wanting to know how to remove newline characters in paragraphs in [this book](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/42324/pg42324.txt) and others for use in a kindle. The desired effect is to have each block that is separated by a blank line to be turned into continuous lines of text. I got the job done for this book with a series of complicated vim substitute commands but I'd rather try and find a better way to get this done for the future.

My hope was to get a vim, perl, sed or awk script I could use for this but I'm open to whatever you people have in mind.

The solution has been found but here is an example input output for those googling this in the future.

Input with newline characters:

```
Letter 1

_To Mrs. Saville, England._


St. Petersburgh, Dec. 11th, 17—.


You will rejoice to hear that no disaster has accompanied the
commencement of an enterprise which you have regarded with such evil
forebodings. I arrived here yesterday, and my first task is to assure
my dear sister of my welfare and increasing confidence in the success
of my undertaking.

I am already far north of London, and as I walk in the streets of
Petersburgh, I feel a cold northern breeze play upon my cheeks, which
braces my nerves and fills me with delight. Do you understand this
feeling? This breeze, which has travelled from the regions towards
which I am advancing, gives me a foretaste of those icy climes.
Inspirited by this wind of promise, my daydreams become more fervent
and vivid. I try in vain to be persuaded that the pole is the seat of
frost and desolation; it ever presents itself to my imagination as the
region of beauty and delight. There, Margaret, the sun is for ever
visible, its broad disk just skirting the horizon and diffusing a...
```

Output without newlines in paragraphs:

```
_To Mrs. Saville, England._


St. Petersburgh, Dec. 11th, 17--.


You will rejoice to hear that no disaster has accompanied the commencement of an enterprise which you have regarded with such evil forebodings. I arrived here yesterday; and my first task is to assure my dear sister of my welfare, and increasing confidence in the success of my undertaking.

I am already far north of London; and as I walk in the streets of Petersburgh, I feel a cold northern breeze play upon my cheeks, which braces my nerves, and fills me with delight. Do you understand this feeling? This breeze, which has travelled from the regions towards which I am advancing, gives me a foretaste of those icy climes. Inspirited by this wind of promise, my day dreams become more fervent and vivid. I try in vain to be persuaded that the pole is the seat of frost and desolation; it ever presents itself to my imagination as the region of beauty and delight. There, Margaret, the sun is for ever visible; its broad disk just skirting the horizon, and diffusing a...
```

Now the vim commands I used initially for the curious:

```
ggVG:norm A<space>   -- adds a space to the end of each line
:%s/\v^\s*$/<++>     -- swaps all blank lines with a unique temporary string
ggVGgJ               -- joins all lines without adding a space
:%s/<++>/\r\r/g      -- replaces all occurrences of my unique string with two newline characters
```

Comment: For such questions always provide sample input and output.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Remove new lines where there's more than one? Show us your `vim` commands and add explanations, thanks.

Comment: Do you want text all left-aligned?

Comment: Do you care if the 2 blank lines between `_To Mrs. Saville, England._` and `St. Petersburgh, Dec. 11th, 17—.` get compressed to a single blank line or not?

Comment: Not for my application, but a slightly more correct solution would be interesting to see. @EdMorton

Comment: OK, [I posted an answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/744906/133219) that will retain whatever blank lines exist between paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the paragraphs already separated by two or more newlines and you only want to remove the newlines inside each paragraph (or better yet, replace newlines with a space), then:

```
perl -00 -lpe 's/\n/ /g' pg42324.txt > pg42324-new.txt
```

- `-00` tells perl to read & process the input one paragraph at a time (a paragraph boundary is two or more newlines)
- `-l` turns on perl's automatic processing of line-endings (or, in this case, paragraph-endings)
- `-p` makes perl run similarly to `sed` - i.e. read and print the input after any modifications by the script.
- `-e` tells perl that the next argument is the script to run

For more details on these options, see `man perlrun`.

Or, to do an in-place edit (with the originally backed up with a .bak extension):

```
perl -i.bak -00 -lpe 's/\n/ /g' pg42324.txt
```

If there are leading or trailing spaces on any lines within paragraphs, you may want to replace multiple spaces with a single space - add `; s/  +/ /g` to the perl script:

```
perl -00 -lpe 's/\n/ /g; s/  +/ /g'
```

---

IMO, though, you're probably better off just treating the entire file as if it's markdown (maybe even going so far as to add markdown formatting for bold, italics, chapter headers, etc) and using [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) or something to convert it from markdown to epub.  After all, markdown is just plain text with optional formatting characters in it. e.g.

```
pandoc pg42324.txt -o pg42324.epub
```

A minimal edit would be to just open the file in `vim` (or whatever) and make sure that there's a blank line between each paragraph.

BTW, [Creating an ebook with pandoc](https://pandoc.org/epub.html) is a short but good general introduction to creating .epub books from text or markdown files.

---

Or, even better, just download the .epub or .mobi version of the book rather than the plain text version - Project Gutenberg provides books in multiple formats.

There are links to download Mary Shelley's Frankenstein in various formats at:

https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/42324

Comment: My reason for not using .epub files was a privacy concern as amazon's supported method was to email it to the kindle which is first sent to a amazon server to convert to a kindle file. This requires an internet connection and I didn't want big daddy Bezos collecting data on me. As a solution, I just found [Calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/) that allows you to convert and send ebooks to a kindle over USB.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `awk` provides a so-called "paragraph mode" by setting `RS` empty, which may come in handy for this case.

GNU `awk`, with its `RT` automatic variable that captures the actual record separators between paragraphs, makes it neat and compact:

```bash
gawk '{$1=$1; print $0 RT}' RS= ORS= pg42324.txt
```

`RS` is set to empty so as to enable paragraph mode.

`ORS` is set to empty so as to print separators explicitly through the `RT` variable only.

---

Or as a more formally correct equivalent, setting `RS` and `ORS` via the dedicated `-v` option, as arguments placed after the script are rather typically reserved to either input filenames or arguments for the script itself:

```bash
gawk -v RS='' -v ORS='' '{$1=$1; print $0 RT}' pg42324.txt
```

Comment: `$1=$1` alone would convert ALL white space in each record to blanks which may not be desirable. You should add `-F'\n'` so that only newlines are converted to blanks.

Comment: Thank you @EdMorton, in full honesty I thought that'd be desired by OP as they apparently want to turn full paragraphs into "seamless streams" of lines. So translating runs of blanks as well as newlines and tabs into single blanks seemed desirable to me. But you're right to suspect otherwise, after all their sample input is not exactly unambiguous :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to normalize new lines/line feeds:

```
wget https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/42324/pg42324.txt
dos2unix pg42324.txt
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n{3,}/\n\n/g' pg42324.txt | less
```

If you want to *edit in place*:

```
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/\n{2,}/\n\n/g' pg42324.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -e '.put for slurp.split(/ \n ** 2..* /)>>.subst(:global, / \n /, " ")>>.trim-leading;'  pg42324.txt > pg42324-new.txt 

#OR

~$ raku -e '.put for slurp.split(/ \n ** 2..* /).map: *.subst(:global, / \n /, " ").trim-leading;'  pg42324.txt > pg42324-new.txt
```

Raku is a programming language in the Perl family. Note in the resulting output (below), the paragraphs starting with, *"The Publishers of the Standard Novels... ."* and *"It is not singular that... ."* each occupy a single line. This pattern continues to the end of the file. In fact, the Raku code converts the original 8028 line file into a mere 903 lines (i.e. paragraphs).

Briefly, the code above `slurp`s the input (i.e. reads all lines at once), and these lines are broken into paragraphs via `split(/ \n ** 2..* /)`, splitting on two-or-more consecutive newlines. A `>>` hyper-operator is used to map into the resulting paragraphs (`map` works also). Each paragraph is `subst` substituted, taking paragraph-internal `\n` newlines and converting them to spaces. Finally, text is left-aligned using `trim-leading`, and output is redirected to a new file (instead of printing to < stdout > ).

[ Leading `.` dots connect the method calls to the `$_` topic variable (in Perl/Raku lingo). Essentially `.put` is an abbreviated form of `$_.put` ].

Sample Output (first 19 lines):

```
The Project Gutenberg EBook of Frankenstein, by Mary W. Shelley
This eBook is for the use of anyone anywhere at no cost and with almost no restrictions whatsoever.  You may copy it, give it away or re-use it under the terms of the Project Gutenberg License included with this eBook or online at www.gutenberg.org
Title: Frankenstein        or, The Modern Prometheus
Author: Mary W. Shelley
Release Date: March 13, 2013 [EBook #42324]
Language: English
*** START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK FRANKENSTEIN ***
Produced by Greg Weeks, Mary Meehan and the Online Distributed Proofreading Team at http://www.pgdp.net
FRANKENSTEIN:
OR,
THE MODERN PROMETHEUS.
BY MARY W. SHELLEY.
AUTHOR OF THE LAST MAN, PERKIN WARBECK, &c. &c.
[Transcriber's Note: This text was produced from a photo-reprint of     the 1831 edition.]
REVISED, CORRECTED,     AND ILLUSTRATED WITH A NEW INTRODUCTION,     BY THE AUTHOR.
LONDON:     HENRY COLBURN AND RICHARD BENTLEY,     NEW BURLINGTON STREET:     BELL AND BRADFUTE, EDINBURGH;     AND CUMMING, DUBLIN.     1831.
INTRODUCTION.
The Publishers of the Standard Novels, in selecting "Frankenstein" for one of their series, expressed a wish that I should furnish them with some account of the origin of the story. I am the more willing to comply, because I shall thus give a general answer to the question, so very frequently asked me--"How I, when a young girl, came to think of, and to dilate upon, so very hideous an idea?" It is true that I am very averse to bringing myself forward in print; but as my account will only appear as an appendage to a former production, and as it will be confined to such topics as have connection with my authorship alone, I can scarcely accuse myself of a personal intrusion.
It is not singular that, as the daughter of two persons of distinguished literary celebrity, I should very early in life have thought of writing. As a child I scribbled; and my favourite pastime, during the hours given me for recreation, was to "write stories." Still I had a dearer pleasure than this, which was the formation of castles in the air--the indulging in waking dreams--the following up trains of thought, which had for their subject the formation of a succession of imaginary incidents. My dreams were at once more fantastic and agreeable than my writings. In the latter I was a close imitator--rather doing as others had done, than putting down the suggestions of my own mind. What I wrote was intended at least for one other eye--my childhood's companion and friend; but my dreams were all my own; I accounted for them to nobody; they were my refuge when annoyed--my dearest pleasure when free.
```

https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NF { buf=buf $0 OFS; next }
{ prtBuf(); print }
END { prtBuf() }

function prtBuf() {
    sub(OFS"$",ORS,buf)
    printf "%s", buf
    buf = ""
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk letter
_To Mrs. Saville, England._


St. Petersburgh, Dec. 11th, 17—.


You will rejoice to hear that no disaster has accompanied the commencement of an enterprise which you have regarded with such evil forebodings. I arrived here yesterday, and my first task is to assure my dear sister of my welfare and increasing confidence in the success of my undertaking.

I am already far north of London, and as I walk in the streets of Petersburgh, I feel a cold northern breeze play upon my cheeks, which braces my nerves and fills me with delight. Do you understand this feeling? This breeze, which has travelled from the regions towards which I am advancing, gives me a foretaste of those icy climes. Inspirited by this wind of promise, my daydreams become more fervent and vivid. I try in vain to be persuaded that the pole is the seat of frost and desolation; it ever presents itself to my imagination as the region of beauty and delight. There, Margaret, the sun is for ever visible, its broad disk just skirting the horizon and diffusing a...
```